# Regex for allowing apostrophe and period

Tags: regex

I have below regex which is used for removing punctuations from a string. What I need is to allow only apostrophes and periods in **between** words such as “Zipf’s”, “e.g”.

```
[^\w\s]
```

Comment: If you use it in some replace, use `([A-Za-z]'[a-zA-Z])|[^\w\s]` and replace with `$1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea to use *non [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)* (where no word-character touches specified characters).

> \B matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters ...

```
[^\w\s.’']|\B[.’']\B
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4PNm7T/1)